# Custom GRPC client stub - stream not started

Tags: android, ssl, grpc

I am trying to access a custom GRPC server (Anki Vector robot) with TLS from my Android app.

I have the proto files in my Android Studio project and all required dependencies are available. Proto files generate the java classes and in my activity I build a channel with OkHttpChannelBuilder. 
Then I create a client stub (tried with async and blocking stubs)

After that I create a request message and send it with the stub.

The code compiles fine and the app runs on my phone. 
However, when the request is sent, I get an error stating that the stream is not started.

I don't see any method to start the stream in all the examples that I could find.

what may be the problem preventing the stream to start ?

error message I get :

```
2019-02-10 01:08:59.303 14691-30895/com.test.anki.grpc D/vectorCTRL: Failed... : 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not started
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:510)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.request(ClientCallImpl.java:367)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall$SimpleForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:44)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall$SimpleForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:44)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCall.request(PartialForwardingClientCall.java:34)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCall.request(ForwardingClientCall.java:22)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.startCall(ClientCalls.java:314)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryRequestCall(ClientCalls.java:280)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.futureUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:189)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:127)
        at Anki.Vector.external_interface.ExternalInterfaceGrpc$ExternalInterfaceBlockingStub.sayText(ExternalInterfaceGrpc.java:3554)
        at com.test.anki.grpc.MainActivity.testapi(MainActivity.java:1106)
        at com.test.anki.grpc.MainActivity$GrpcTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1003)
        at com.test.anki.grpc.MainActivity$GrpcTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:996)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

my code is :

```
       ClientInterceptor clientInterceptor = new ClientInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> methodDescriptor, CallOptions callOptions, Channel channel) {
                // Might need to try to inject the token using that?
                return new ClientInterceptors.CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(channel.newCall(methodDescriptor, callOptions)) {
                    @Override
                    protected void checkedStart(Listener listener, Metadata metadata) throws Exception {
                        Metadata.Key<String> key = Metadata.Key.of("authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
                        metadata.put(key, token);
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext=null ;
        try {
            sslContext  = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext .init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
            SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext );
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        Channel channel=null;
        try {
            //ManagedChannel channel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(ipaddr, Integer.valueOf(port))
                    channel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(ipaddr, Integer.valueOf(port))
                    //.overrideAuthority("Vector")
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                    .intercept(clientInterceptor)
                    .build();

            //ExternalInterfaceGrpc.ExternalInterfaceStub externalInterfaceStub = ExternalInterfaceGrpc.newStub(channel);
            ExternalInterfaceGrpc.ExternalInterfaceBlockingStub externalInterfaceBlockingStub = ExternalInterfaceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

            Messages.SayTextRequest sayTextRequest = Messages.SayTextRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setText("Yolo")
                    .build();

            Messages.SayTextResponse res = externalInterfaceBlockingStub.sayText(sayTextRequest);
            Log.d(TAG, res.getStatus().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            pw.flush();
            Log.d(TAG,String.format("Failed... : %n%s", sw));
        } finally {
            Log.d(TAG,"finally");
            /*
            try {
                 if(channel!=null) {((ManagedChannel) channel).shutdown().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);}
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            */
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClientCall` needs to have `start()` called. `start()` doesn't need to be called if using the stubs, as the stubs themselves will call `start()`. But interceptors are exposed to `start()`.

The problem is with your `clientInterceptor`:

```java
protected void checkedStart(Listener listener, Metadata metadata) throws Exception {
    Metadata.Key<String> key = Metadata.Key.of("authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
    metadata.put(key, token);
    // FIXME: Missing call to delegate().start(listener, metadata);
}
```

The stub called `start()` which eventually called your interceptor's `checkedStart()`, but then the interceptor didn't call start on the real ClientCall.

Note that you have no need for using `CheckedForwardingClientCall` since your `checkedStart()` is not throwing any exceptions. `ForwardingClientCall` is the more common class to use. (Override `start()` instead of `checkedStart()`).

Comment: thanks. so you seem to have a solution. but I didn't understand what to do as a fix. you propose to change CheckedForwardingClientCall  with ForwardingClientCall . However, when I do that , I get a "can not resolve symbol" error for ForwardingClientCall  Also, you say that the interceptor did not call start on the real ClientCall. How shall I do that ?

Comment: https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ForwardingClientCall.html . Feel free to use SimpleForwardingClientCall. I pointed out how to call start within the FIXME: `delegate().start(listener, metadata);`